# React Isomorphic Fetch not actually posting

Tags: javascript, reactjs, isomorphic-fetch-api

I'm creating a website using React, one of the steps involves creating an event. I've created a step that posts to an API using isomorphic fetch.

```js
import fetch from "isomorphic-fetch";

export function createEvent(data) {
    console.log(data);
    return fetch("whatson/createEvent.php", {
        method: "POST",
        body: JSON.stringify(data),
        headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json"
        },
        redirect: "follow"
    }).then(response => {
        if (response.status >= 200 && response.status < 300) {
            alert("Success");
            console.log(response);
            return response;
        } else {
            console.log("Something went wrong");
            console.log(response);
        }
    });
}
```

I've stepped through the response and it says that it's A-OK, 200 response status etc, however, nothing actually gets added to the database.

If I use the same data that is posted and call the same API address in postman it works fine and the data is added to the database so I'm fairly confident that it's not the API itself and more something to do with the above code.

Comment: Have you looked at the Network tab of the Developer Tools to see if the request look like the request you send with Postman?

Comment: @Tholle I have, the console.log of the data at the start is what I used in the body for postman

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably, you need to `return response.json()`:

```
import fetch from "isomorphic-fetch";

export function createEvent(data) {
  console.log(data);
  return fetch("whatson/createEvent.php", {
    method: "POST",
    body: JSON.stringify(data),
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json"
    },
    redirect: "follow"
  }).then(response => {
    if (response.status >= 200 && response.status < 300) {
      alert("Success");
      return response.json();
    } else {
      console.log("Something went wrong");
      console.log(response);
    }
  }).then(json => console.log(json));
}
```

Comment: That worked....and I have no idea why haha. Can you explain what that's done? The returned data isn't actually used for anything. The page just refreshes and shows the newly added data.

Comment: Honestly, I have a very vague idea why it worked haha. Maybe it has to do with not closing the connection server-side until a client reads json? It's weird, I kind of deduced the answer intuitively.